# pymodbus on RasPi read_holding_registers Returns none From Simulator

Tags: raspberry-pi, modbus, pymodbus3

I'm trying to read holding registers from a Modbus simulator, but when I print the value in Python, I get a "none" object. The simulator does send a response, but Python seems to not receive it.

I've googled for a day and have tried everything I've found: including unit number, different Python modbus clients, different simulators, etc. No luck.

Any ideas or suggestions are very welcomed!!Please let me know if there is any information I should supply to help.

I can successfully write to the holding registers, and the simulator sends the transmission below:

"RX:01 03 00 00 00 01
RX:84 0A
Read Register from 0 for 1
TX:01 03 02 00 05 78 47"

[image]
Simulator Transmissions

[image]
Simulator Registers

The Python output that I get is:
"Connection:True
None"

[image]

If I try the print(result.registers), I get the error: "Error: ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'registers')"

Version Info:
Python: 3.4.2
Modbus: pymodbus3
Simulator: MOD_RSsim Version 8.20
USB-to-Modbus converter: UTEK Model:UT-890A (connected to RasPi)
USB-to-RS232 convertor: ATEN Model: GUC232A (connected to laptop)

```html
import pymodbus3
from pymodbus3.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient

client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', address=1, timeout=1000, port="/dev/ttyUSB0", bytesize=8, stopbits=1, baudrate=9600, parity='E')

connection = client.connect()
print ('Connection:{}'.format(connection))

write = client.write_registers(0, 5, unit = 1)
time.sleep(0.3)
result = client.read_holding_registers(address=0x00, count=1, unit = 0x01)
time.sleep(1)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought this is a bug if you installed pymodbus3 by pip.
Here is a issue link:  [pymodbus3 issue](https://github.com/uzumaxy/pymodbus3/issues/3).
I suggested you use pymodbus since it support python3 now [Just a Note : Pymodbus for python3 is officially supported](https://github.com/uzumaxy/pymodbus3/issues/7), or you can install pymodbus3 by pymodbus3 master branch source code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I can still write the registers using pymodbus, and I get a different error when trying to read: "Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Unable to decode request".  It feels like progress! I'll work on it a bit more tonight or tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: It looked like a progress, if any questions ,let me know

Comment: I think it's a problem with the checksum that is being returned from the simulator. After turning on logging, I get "Unable to decode response Modbus Error: Unknown response 127" even when I write_registers. The simulator register does change, but I still get the error in the log. I didn't get to work on this as much as I wanted today, so not much to report. Still getting the same error when trying to read_registers. :(

Comment: Ok, I have done some local tests in my PC, and the result showed pymodbus and pymodbus3  which installed by pip didn't work well. But the pymodbus3 which installed by pymodbus3 master branch in github works well, by the way, you should change```print(result)``` to ```print(result.registers) ``` to see  the read_holding_registers.

Comment: Another possibility is that your hardware got some problems. So I suggested you do the test in local PC by using virtual port.